# Axes titles for a plot with cufflinks

Tags: python, plotly, cufflinks

I am trying to crate a surface plot of a pandas DataFrame using cufflinks.

I would like to have customized axes titles (`title_1`,`title_2` and `title_3`) and a plot title with a math symbol. However the plot I get does not display my axes titles and in the plot title I only see the math symbol but not "My title with ". Why it does not work and how to fix it?

I am working in a Jupyter notebook.

```
import cufflinks as cf
cf.set_config_file(offline=True, dimensions=((1000,600)), theme = 'white')
pd.DataFrame([(1,2),(3,4)]).iplot(kind = 'surface', xTitle = "title_1", \
                              yTitle = "title_2" , zTitle = "title_3",\
                              title = r"My title with $\sigma$")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `iplot` returns a Plotly figure, you can provide a layout object, as follow (refer to Plotly documentation to understand how layout works):

```py
import cufflinks as cf
cf.set_config_file(offline=True, dimensions=((1000,600)), theme = 'white')
pd.DataFrame([(1,2),(3,4)]).iplot(
    kind = 'surface',
    layout = {
        "scene": {
            "xaxis": {"title": "x axis"},
            "yaxis": {"title": "y axis"},
            "zaxis": {"title": "z axis"},
        },
        "title": r"My title with $\sigma$"
    })
```

[image]

As for why in the title you only see the rendered sigma and not the text, that is a bug with Plotly. Nothing we can do about it, for now.

Comment: Do you know why it does not work with `xTitle`, `yTitle ` and `zTitle `? Is it also a bug?

Comment: No idea, first time I tried cufflinks :) Might be a bug.